# Ps2 don't recognize usb flash drive

Tags: technical-issues, ps2

I have formatted my usb flash drive in FAT32, but my ps2 doesn't recognise the usb drive with mcboot installed in memory card. Neither ulaunchelf don't recognise usb drive. I have tried two different usb drives and the problem remains. Do you have any ideas why my ps2 doesn't recognise the usb drives? There is a case of having a problem with hardware?

Comment: Hi Theodore, and welcome to Arqade. Your question has nothing to do with gaming, however, and I suggest you ask it at [Super User SE](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: If you installed FreeMCBoot correctly, there should be a program called Open PS2 Loader or OPL, depending on the version of FreeMCBoot installed. This program will format your USB so that FreeMCBoot recognizes the drive on plug in

Comment: It's specifically off-topic on SuperUser but it might be allowed on Arqade.

Comment: Right, thanks for the heads-up @HazardousGlitch!

Comment: Anything [here](https://forums.afterdawn.com/threads/can-ps2-detect-any-usb-disk.704393/) that can help you out (like [this](https://forums.afterdawn.com/threads/can-ps2-detect-any-usb-disk.704393/#post-4744122))?

Comment: @Joachim unfortunately no, maybe me ps2 usb ports are dead.